# Ajax for other user?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

how I can send ajax request to other user? 
Example: I send message with ajax to other user. How I can send ajax him and do some actions?

My Code:

```
$.post( "sendmessage.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
   .done(function( data ) {
   alert( "Message sended: " + data );
});
```

Comment: How do you mean other user? Someone on another computer? You can't. You can send data to a server, and the other user can connect to that same server and retrieve date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how **AJAX** works. It can only deal with **server**.

That means all your AJAX requests have to be directed to server.

In the server side your request commonly should affect the database (create new message, for example). After creating new field in database => server can return a response back. And you'll see that operation was succeeded.

So, in order to see requested message, user on the other side should request new data from server and see your newly created message.

```
$.get( "messages.php")
   .done(function(data) {
       alert("My messages: " + data );
       // todo: render messages to page
   }
);
```

[image: How AJAX works]

#### References:

- https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: But in real time I can't get messages for other user?

Comment: Yes, you can! If you want strong subscription to your server and front in order to receive & send & read messages for every server request **instantly** - I recommend you to refer to **WebSockets**

They're created to provide this ability. WebSockets could be used in chats, for example, when you instantly want to see all new messages from other users every time they request one to server. So, you won't need AJAX calls every 5 minutes (for example) to refresh your data from server.

Learn more: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm